# Check Length of string - Linux

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

I have a file that has a couple thousand lines. I need to make sure that a string is consistently 9 chars long throughout the file and if not, It will kick it back and throw an error everywhere the string is not 9 chars long.

```
xxxxxxxxx,xxx
```

I need the first 9 char to always be 9 chars long and if not, throw an error out.

```
------ ERRORS ------
Errors found at _, _, _, _, _, _ ...etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'length($1) !== 9 {print "ERROR at line "NR}' file
```

- `F,` sets the field delimiter to `,`
- `length($1) !== 9` checks if the first field is 9 chars long
- `print "ERROR at line "NR` prints the error message along with the line number `NR`

Comment: could I add on that and make sure the value of ($2) <= 9999 ?

Comment: Sure, it would be `length($1) !== 9 || length($2) !== 9999 { print ...`

Comment: Would that print out all the $2 that are not 9999 or only the ones that are >  9999?

Comment: Use `length($2) > 9999` in that case. (Sorry, I overlooked that)

Comment: The saying "Not all hero's wear capes" is all about you right now, man. Thank you.

Comment: Who says I don't wear a cape? Hihi! :) You are welcome!

Comment: 1 more question. Would I use a value($2) over using length($2)

Comment: I don't get that question. What means `value($2)`?

Comment: so the $1 is an ID and I need it to be a fixed 9 digits. $2 is a quantity and I need that value to be under 9999 or kick back the error.

Comment: Ah.. Now I got it.. Then simply use `length($1) !== 9 || $2 > 9999 { print ...`

Comment: My grandma is very dear to me and she told me to respect everyone, so I'll say thank you the way she would. Bless your heart.

Comment: I don't know if you're still there, but I ran into an issue. Is there anyway I can run this command and after it runs if there was an error to exit out of the script and throw an error message? @hek2mgl

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` to list non-matches. Using GNU grep:

```
grep -vEn '^[^,]{9},' file
```

This lists all lines (prefixed with line number) that don't start with exactly 9 non-commas followed by a comma. Example:

```
$ cat file
1234567890,foo
123456789,bar
12345678,baz

$ grep -vEn '^[^,]{9},' file
1:1234567890,foo
3:12345678,baz
```

Comment: To show lines that do not also have a second column <= 9999: `grep -vEn '^[^,]{9},\d{1,4}$' file`

Comment: To allow for white-space: `grep -vEn '^\s*[^,]{9}\s*,\s*[0-9]{1,4}\s*$' file`